# Py Selenium find elements inside element not working

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to **scrape** a website for news on Real Estate funds. My code gets Process finished with exit code 0 but none of the content is printed.

```
driver.get('https://fiis.com.br/atualizacoes/')
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reports-list"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[1]/div').click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text(d_N1_2).click()
d_N1_2_click = driver.find_element_by_link_text(d_N1_2)
elements = d_N1_2_click.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

time.sleep(1)

for elem in elements:
    print(elem.get_attribute("primary-title"))
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
    print(elem.get_attribute("secondary-title"))
```

Here is html:

```
<li>
<a href="http://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/exibirDocumento?id=84320&amp;amp;flnk" target="_blank">
<span class="primary-title">FISD11</span>
<span class="secondary-title">Informe Mensal - 02/2020</span>
<input type="hidden" class="report-content">
</a>
</li>
```

I am doing this to add it later to a dataframe, with an order from `primary-text` `secondary-text` `href`

d_N1_2

```
today=datetime.date.today()
five_day=datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
d_N1=today+five_day
d_N1_2 = d_N1.strftime('%d.%m.%y')
```

Comment: `elem` represents an `li` element which does not have the attributes you need. The elements with the attributes you are searching for are in child elements of the individual `li` elements.

Comment: How can i reference the child elements inside the li? And the html i sent represents just one news, there is a list of news bellow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How it should be:

```
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    driver.get('https://fiis.com.br/atualizacoes/')
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-type="date"]'))).click()

    today = datetime.date.today()
    five_day = datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
    d_N1 = today + five_day
    d_N1_2 = d_N1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    # //a[normalize-space(.)='06.03.20']
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'li[data-item="{d_N1_2}"]'))).click()

    elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'li[data-item="{d_N1_2}"] li')))
    for elem in elements:
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', elem)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of(elem))
        print(elem.find_element_by_css_selector('span.primary-title').text,
              elem.find_element_by_css_selector('span.secondary-title').text,
              elem.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: That works really well! The next part of code i need to implement but i dont know quite well right now is to print these datas to a pandas df, with ticker, news and href columns. Any tips on that?

Answer (score 1):

Untested but you can try something along the lines of the following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import datetime, time

today=datetime.date.today()
five_day=datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
d_N1=today+five_day
d_N1_2 = d_N1.strftime('%d.%m.%y')
print(d_N1_2)
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://fiis.com.br/atualizacoes/')
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reports-list"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a[1]/div').click()
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_link_text(d_N1_2).click()
time.sleep(4)
d_N1_2_click = driver.find_element_by_link_text(d_N1_2)
elements = d_N1_2_click.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

print(elements) # if empty, you'll need to fix something above

time.sleep(1)

for elem in elements:
    a = elem.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
    print(a.find_element_by_css_selector("span.primary-title").text)
    print(a.get_attribute("href"))
    print(a.find_element_by_css_selector("span.secondary-title").text)
```

Comment: I got Process finished with exit code 0 and not a single print

Comment: What is the value of `d_N1_2`? Post your complete code; include all imports too. I do not have python on this machine so I'm posting from memory.

Comment: That is used to get the selenium browser to click yesterday's date and expand a dropdown list witch has the news inside them. I am editing and posting my code

Comment: Add a `print(elements)` before the for loop. I'm guessing `d_N1_2_click.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')` is returning an empty list. If so, then you'll need to fix that part of the code.

Comment: You may also want to add a delay after each of your clicks as the page takes a few seconds to respond to the clicks.

Comment: I just tried that and it is true, elements is an empty list. How to you sugest i get only the content from yesterday news?

Comment: As I suggested earlier, try adding `time.sleep(n)` after each call to `.click()`

Comment: Thank you for the help!